# How to setup cortex a76 in gem5?

Tags: gem5

can someone please help me or direct me on how to configure ARM cortex a76 in gem5?
will making changes to configs/common/cores/arm/ex_big.py to a76 configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

For the ISA interface purely, we have very few "enable this feature"
flags in the config, for the most part it is all on an "enable
everything that is implemented by default" basis.

For performance modeling, I believe not enough public information is
made available for accurate modeling, have a look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A76 for some very high level
publicly known parameters you could try to replicate with custom configs
such as out-of-order or cache sizes. Those parameters I mentioned are accessible on `fs.py` with `--cpu-type` and `--caches --l2cache --l1d_size=1024 --l1i_size=1024 --l2_size=1024 --l3_size=1024I`.

Mailing list thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16323.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was trying to find the architecture details of the previous gen. of a76 (a53, a57, a72). In specific i am looking for the the number of physical integer and floating point registers for these cores (a53 or a57 or a72). Could someone tell me or direct me where i can find these details?

Comment: @ssg sorry, but I don't know if that information is public or how to find it :-)