# Measuring speedup with gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to use gem5 to measure the speedup between some parallel scripts (using openMP), but I'm not sure which of the available CPU types I should use to measure their execution times, some papers say that the O3 types offer precise timing measurements, but others don't specify.

Would different types of CPUs affect the speedup calculation, or it wouldn't matter as long as I used the same one every time?
And if they make a difference. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extremely difficult question. You have to understand what gem5 models model, and what real CPU or future CPU you want to model, and if the accuracy is enough. A quick gem5 CPU overview [can be found here](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-cpu-types). But to determine what the real hardware looks like, you have to search for public information on a specific hardware of interest, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936348/how-to-setup-cortex-a76-in-gem5/54941559#54941559).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped me get into the right track